# Update SCNPhysicsBody when scaling SCNNode

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit, scnnode

I know that SCNPhysicsBody dont scale when the node scale, but I haven't found a great solution to fix this. I want to scale the node and then update the SCNPhysicsBody to node after scaling it.

```
let box = SCNBox(width: 0.2, height: 0.3, length: 0.4, chamferRadius: 0.1)
box.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue
var boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: box)
boxNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
boxNode.position.x += 0.5

boxNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.static, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: box, options: nil))

sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
```

[image]

Has anyone come up with a great solution to this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
let nodeScale = SCNVector3(0.5,0.5,0.5)

 boxNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.static, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: box, options:  [SCNPhysicsShape.Option.scale: nodeScale]))
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!